# Formik. Dirty check

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

Can someone tell me how to make the addition of data work together with the check through dirty. The rendering of the button works, but when I click on it the initialState gets new data and is updated, hence the dirty should return to false, but it is not.

state:

```
  const [store, setStore] = useState<UserDataType>({
    firstName: 'Artem',
    lastName: 'Bugay',
    email: '',
    age: '',
    country: '',
    region: '',
    placeOfWork: '',
    occupation: '',
  });
```

Function what save changes to local store:

```
  const changeState = (values: UserDataType) => {
      setStore(values);
  };
```

Component return:

```
  return (
<Styled.WrapperContainer>
  <Styled.Container>
    <GlobalStyled.Title>Your profile</GlobalStyled.Title>
    <Formik initialValues={store} onSubmit={updateProfile}>
      {({ values, isSubmitting, handleChange, dirty }) => {
        return (
          <GlobalStyled.FormFormik>
            {console.log('dirty', dirty)}
            <Styled.Field
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              label="First Name"
              value={values?.firstName}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <Styled.Field
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              label="Last Name"
              value={values?.lastName}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <Styled.Field
              type="email"
              name="email"
              label="Email"
              value={values?.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            ...
              <Styled.ButtonAntd
                data-testid="profile"
                htmlType="submit"
                disabled={!dirty}
                onClick={() => changeState(values)}
              >
                Update
                {/* <Spinner loading={isLoading === StateStatus.Pending} size={20} /> */}
              </Styled.ButtonAntd>
          </GlobalStyled.FormFormik>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  </Styled.Container>
</Styled.WrapperContainer>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
        setSubmitting(true);
        setTimeout(async () => {
          resetForm({ values });
        }, 100);
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `setStore`, you have variable `{values}`.

Every time field value  changes, you have updated data in `{values}`. You can check with your custom function `onChange` element you create. Check this [info](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation) too.

Also, you can check fields data with advanced [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup).